# Esqueleto/raw SQL -- Sorting a query by the result of a sort on another table?

Tags: sql, haskell, yesod, esqueleto

I actually am a little new to how SQL works -- i've always let my ORM's handle everything for me.  But this in this case Persistent doesn't expose this kind of functionality so I'm at lost at what to do.

I have a many-to-many relationship:

```
+------------+
| Entries    |
+----+-------+
| id | date  |
+----+-------+
| 1  | Jan 1 |
+----+-------+
| 2  | Jan 2 |
+----+-------+
| 3  | Jan 3 |
+----+-------+

+------------+
| Tags       |
+------------+
| id | label |
+----+-------+
| 1  | Apple |
+----+-------+
| 2  | Boat  |
+----+-------+
| 3  | Car   |
+----+-------+

+-------------------+
| EntryTags         |
+----------+--------+
| entry_id | tag_id |
+----------+--------+
| 1        | 1      |
+----------+--------+
| 1        | 2      |
+----------+--------+
| 2        | 2      |
+----------+--------+
| 3        | 3      |
+----------+--------+
```

And I want to sort tags primarily by the date of their most recent entry (descending), secondarily by their label (ascending).

Tag `Car`'s most recent entry is on Jan 3rd, so it goes first.
Tag `Apple`'s most recent entry is January 2nd, but so is tag `Boat`.  However, the label `Apple` comes before the label `Boat` alphabetically, so `Apple` is 2nd and `Boat` is 3rd:

```
returns:
1. Tag w/ id 3
2. Tag w/ id 1
3. Tag w/ id 2
```

Through my research I've figured out that I need some kind of combination of joins to do this.  However so far I've only found soutions for one-to-many relations (sorting topics in a thread by their most recent post), and I think I understand them, but none involving these three-way joins for many-to-many relations.

I'm including raw sql as a possible answer because I think I'm really just asking for the sql way to do it, and even though I'm using Esqueleto for my SQL bindings, I think that once I understand the SQL, the translation to Esqueleto will be straightforward.  I'm using postgresql as my backend, but I'd rather not use postgres-specific things because my bindings are for general backends.

Anyone have any idea where I can start?  What kind of joins should I be looking at and how do I sort through most recent entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution:

```
select t.id as tag_id, t.label as tag, max(date) as date from Tags t
join EntryTags et on t.id=et.tag_id
join Entries e on e.id=et.entry_id
group by t.label,t.id
order by date desc,tag
```

which returns:

```
tag_id  tag    date   
------  -----  -----  
1       Apple  jan 3  
3       Car    jan 3  
2       Boat   jan 2
```

(In your data, Apple's most recent entry is January 3, not January 2.)

Joins in Postgres are implicity "inner joins". If you may have tags without entries, you will want to change the joins to left joins.

Comment: It works if the tag id is not needed which is not clear from the question.

Comment: Updated to include tag id. I agree the desired output isn't quite clear in the question. @justin, please clarify if this is not the output you need.

Comment: output is sufficient, i just need a way to reference the row in some shape or form.  i just wasn't sure how to sort.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/339ad/1)

Your sample data does not fit the text. The table entrytags should be

```
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(2, 2),
(2, 1),
(3, 3);

select id, label
from (
    select distinct on (t.id) e.date, t.label, t.id
    from
        entries e
        inner join
        entrytags et on et.entry_id = e.id
        inner join
        tags t on t.id = et.tag_id
    order by t.id, e.date desc, t.label
) s
order by "date" desc, label
```

Comment: thank you for the correction and the solution :)  my apologies though, my choice for best answer was a little arbitrary as both solutions seemed to work, but i still had trouble getting it to work in my ORM so my final solution was a bit of a mix of both.